# How to remove category base from URL with permalink set to "/%postname%/"

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, permalinks

Currently, I have two categories to separate my WordPress blog posts.

- site.com/category/slow/
- site.com/category/fast/

As you can see, my site's category base is 'category'.

My permalink settings on the Dashboard under Settings->Permalinks is set to "site.com/%postname%/".

This means that all my blog posts will appear like this: "site.com/post-title/" regardless of which category I assign the post to.

The thing is, I want to remove the category base from the URL so that they become:

- site.com/slow/
- site.com/fast/

And at the same time, without altering the permalink setting so that my blog posts' URL continue to look like "site.com/post-title/". How can I achieve these?

Here's the solution after I modified a bit the code I found:

```
// Remove category base
function no_category_base_permastruct() {
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite -> extra_permastructs['category']['struct'] = '%category%';
}
add_action('init', 'no_category_base_permastruct');

// Add our custom category rewrite rules
function no_category_base_rewrite_rules($category_rewrite) {
//var_dump($category_rewrite); // For Debugging

$category_rewrite = array();
$categories = get_categories(array('hide_empty' => false));
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $category_nicename = $category -> slug;
    if ($category -> parent == $category -> cat_ID)// recursive recursion
        $category -> parent = 0;
    elseif ($category -> parent != 0)
        $category_nicename = get_category_parents($category -> parent, false, '/', true) . $category_nicename;
    $category_rewrite['(' . $category_nicename . ')/(?:feed/)?(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]';
    $category_rewrite['(' . $category_nicename . ')/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
    $category_rewrite['(' . $category_nicename . ')/?$'] = 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]';
}
// Redirect support from Old Category Base
global $wp_rewrite;
$old_category_base = get_option('category_base') ? get_option('category_base') : 'category';
$old_category_base = trim($old_category_base, '/');
$category_rewrite[$old_category_base . '/(.*)$'] = 'index.php?category_redirect=$matches[1]';

//var_dump($category_rewrite); // For Debugging
return $category_rewrite;
}
add_filter('category_rewrite_rules', 'no_category_base_rewrite_rules');

// Add 'category_redirect' query variable
function no_category_base_query_vars($public_query_vars) {
$public_query_vars[] = 'category_redirect';
return $public_query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'no_category_base_query_vars');

// Redirect if 'category_redirect' is set
function no_category_base_request($query_vars) {
//print_r($query_vars); // For Debugging
if (isset($query_vars['category_redirect'])) {
    $catlink = trailingslashit(get_option('home')) . user_trailingslashit($query_vars['category_redirect'], 'category');
    status_header(301);
    header("Location: $catlink");
    exit();
}
return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('request', 'no_category_base_request');
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your ,htaccess File

RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ category/file_name.php?value=$1

Comment: Thanks for your help. When performing the rewrite, what should I replace the *file_name.php* with? What is the purpose of including *?value=$1*? I'm not good at rewriting .htaccess. Please explain. Thank you.

Comment: Can you upload your code on GitHub? or define your problem much batter so I can help you directly

Comment: Mudit, I've rephrased the description with the code omitted so that it's easier to understand my requirement. Please take a look again. Appreciate your help.

Comment: [Click Here](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-url-rewrite/) Read this blog maybe it'll help you

Comment: The blog you gave me got me inspired that I should look in the direction of using $wp_rewrite. After some searching, I found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215150/how-to-remove-wordpress-category-from-url-and-have-a-custom-pagination-parameter) and modify the code a bit to fit my requirements. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your welcome. Join My page on Facebook you can ask any question regarding PHP there. [Click Here](HTTP://facebook.com/codehuts)

Comment: Facebook says "This page isn't available" after I clicked your link.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Entered wrong url. Http://www.facebook.com/codehunts